# Python - add information to items in a list thereby creating a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
```

I'm looking up info for each item in the list via some arbitrary function, and want to add the results so the list becomes:

```
list1 = [(1,a),(2,b),(3,x)]
```

How to best accomplish this in Python3?

```
for item in list1:
    newinfo = some_arbitrary_function(item)
    item = (item, newinfo)
```

Does not appear to work.

Comment: Where do a, b, and x come from?

Comment: We don't downvote questions because we think the OP is stupid or the answer should be obvious. We downvote questions because they're poorly specified or it's too difficult to tell how they should be answered. At least, that's what's supposed to be happening (I didn't downvote here).

Comment: a, b, and x are the results of arbitrary function() acting on 1,2 and 3 (say a mysql lookup, or other some equation) as indicated by the pseudo-code example I provide. For this case -- it's irrelevant.

Comment: But based on the comemnts, I've update to make it more clear what I'm asking. Communication again proves much more useful than a drive-by downvote.

Comment: did any of the answers solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a list comprehension:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
result = [(item, function(item)) for item in lst]
```

Using `list` as a name is not a good idea, you'll shadow the original `list` builtin making it inaccessible later in your code.

In case you want to keep the reference to the original list:

```
lst[:] = [(item, function(item)) for item in lst]
```

Comment: This is indeed the most pythonic way, but will create a new list. (The OP did not specify if the operation is intended to be in-place.)

Comment: understood about list name -- just used it here for purpose of explanation (ie: I intended a list, not a tuple to begin with)

Comment: @Trees4theForest You have a list of tuples in your expected output, just like I've done

Comment: This is a nice method.  It creates `[(1, a), (2, b)...]` which is what you asked in your op @Trees4theForest

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to assign a list item with the iteration variable (`item` in your case). In fact, there is nothing special about the variable `item` compared to an assignment with `=`. If the operation is intended to be in-place, you should do

```
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    list[i] = (item, func(item))
```

Also, you should not name your list `list`, because it will hide the built-in type `list`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to change the values in the list to go from a single to a tuple containing the original value and the result of some lookup on that value. This should do what you want.

```
zzz = [1,2,3]
i = 0
for num in zzz:
    zzz[i] = (num, somefunc(num))
    i += 1
```

running this

```
zzz = [1,2,3]
i = 0
for num in zzz:
    zzz[i] = (num, 8)
    i += 1
```

gives the results zzz = [(1,8), (2,8), (3,8)]

Answer (score 0):

If you have `list1 = [1,2,3]` and `list2 = [x,y,z]`, `zip(list1, list2)` will give you what you're looking for. You will need to iterate over the first list with the function to find `x, y, z` and put it in a list.

`zip(list1, list2)`

> [(1, x), (2, y), (3, z)]

Comment: but it's iterative -- not 1-1 list merge. I guess I could build list2 from list one then zip -- but this seems overly complex

Comment: Create the second list as a comprehension which calls the function:  zip(list, [f(x) for x in list])

Comment: `list2 = [function(item) for item in list1]`
`zip(list1, list2)`